# Maven war plugin: Is all dependencies specified in pom get added to war?

Tags: java, maven

I use `maven-war-plugin` in my pom to build my Vaadin application. My question is, if I added an unnecessary dependency (dependent library is not actually used in code) to my pom, Will `maven-war-plugin` still bundle the dependency into the war file it generates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the *scope* you specify in the `<dependency>` tag.  Consider the following dependency tag:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The `provided` scope tells Maven to use the `log4j` JAR when compiling but to *exclude* it from the build, so it would not appear in your WAR.  If, on the other hand, you used a scope of `compile` or `runtime`, then it *would* appear in the WAR.

If you don't specify any `<scope>`, then the default is `compile`, which means that the depedency *will* appear in the build output.

Comment: So if I do not add `provided` element, it would appear in war?